# JTextPane inserting large text problem

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextpane

I've a problem: firstly I load some large text from file. After that I want to display it in my JTextPane. For inserting text into JTextPane I use:

```
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
 {

 public void run()
 {
   textPane.setText(someLargeString);
  } 
});
```

But while my text inserts into JTextPane all UI is frozen.

Is there any ability to insert large String into JTextPane but without UI freezing?

Thanks

P.S.
Process of loading data is in another thread. But after data is loaded I need to put it into JTextPane. So I'm invoking setting text in swing. But my UI freeze. Why?

Comment: Please quantify _large_?

Comment: @trashgod The size of my String is nearly 300 Kbytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The size of my String is nearly 300 Kbytes

If `JTextArea` is an acceptable alternative, it can accept > 300 KiB in ~1 second.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536178 */
public class JTextAreaPasteTest {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                display();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void display() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        String testStr = "Paste text here.";
        JTextArea wrapArea = new JTextArea(testStr, 20, 40);
        wrapArea.setLineWrap(true);
        wrapArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        wrapArea.setCaretPosition(testStr.length());
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(wrapArea));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) After changing JTextPane to JTextArea application works faster.

Answer (score 4):

You should not call `setText` on the Swing EDT;
`setText` is thread-safe, see the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29).  `setText` has more to do with the underlying `AbstractDocument` than with Swing.  `setText` obtains a lock on the document before modifying it.

However `getText` must be called from the Swing EDT.

Comment: Sadly, this feature is [absent in version 7](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: @thrashgod Will there be any "thread safe" method left in Swing? or will everything go through the EDT?  How could @stemm avoid the GUI freeze from `setText` in that case?

Comment: I haven't found any yet in casual browsing, but the `EventQueue` API remains intact.

Answer (score 3):

May be some of the tips could help as well
http://java-sl.com/JEditorPanePerformance.html

trashgod's answer is correct if you need just plain text. If you have text with styles you need the JEditorPane/JTextPane.

Comment: +1 This is a particularly useful answer, as others may see `JTextPane` in the title.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).
Here is the [Java trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for it.

Answer (score 0):

you could put the data load into another thread.

Comment: Of course, process of loading data is in another thread. But after loading data I use SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){textPane.setText(someLargeString);}}).